# Mysql return value as 0 in the fetch result

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have this two tables,

```
-- 
-- Table structure for table `t1`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `pid` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `pname` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `t1`
-- 

INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('p1', 'pro1');
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES ('p2', 'pro2');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `t2`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `pid` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `year` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `t2`
-- 

INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES ('p1', 2009, 50);
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES ('p1', 2010, 60);
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES ('p3', 2007, 200);
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES ('p4', 2008, 501);
```

my query is,

```
SELECT *
FROM `t1`
LEFT JOIN `t2` ON t1.pid = t2.pid
```

Getting the result,

```
pid     pname   pid     year    price
p1      pro1    p1    2009    50
p1      pro1    p1    2010    60
p2      pro2    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

My question is, i want to get the price value is 0 instead of NULL.  How can i write the query to getting the price value is 0.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `IFNULL`

```
SELECT pid,pname,pid,year,IFNULL(price,0)
  FROM `t1`
  LEFT JOIN `t2` 
    ON (t1.pid = t2.pid)
```

IFNULL(field_to_test, value_to_show) will return 'value_to_show' when the field 'field_to_test' is null, when field_to_test is not null, it is returned directly.

Comment: I think its IFNULL in MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull